# GCM/ APNS on asp.net 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-mobile-services, .net-core

I am currently working on a ASP.Net 5 project, and I want to support core 5 dnx - I have been searching the web for ages, and all the libraries that allow me to use push notifications are not supported by core 5 dnx, so do you know any that do?

I have looked into Azure Mobile Services and PushSharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Mobile Services will likely not support ASP.NET5 or Core 5 DNX.  You want to look at [Azure Mobile Apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-value-prop-what-is/).  You can deploy ASP.NET5 apps to Azure App Service no problem.

That said, Notification Hubs does not support ASP.NET5 or Core 5 DNX yet (see [docs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-overview/)).  You will need to use [the REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn223264.aspx) to communicate with Notification Hubs from ASP.NET5.  Note that the Server SDKs are just wrappers around the REST API, so you will get the same functionality.